# Assign a number to every user input

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is the following I have a checkbox and two text input where the user has to enter their order and for every order I want to asign a number but I do not know how to do so using javascript and HTML. I tried adding one everytime the order button is clicked but it did not seem to work

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="condiments" id="condiments">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
  <label for="bigger">Make theese bigger:</label>
  <select id="bigger"></select>
</form>
```

```js
var order = 0;

document.getElementById("orders").addEventListener("click", numOrder);

function numOrder() {
  var setOrder= document.getElementById("orders");
  setOrder.value = order;
  order++;
}
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox ? Please add your HTML as well. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you showed us the HTML you need help with...

Comment: your  `var = orders = 0` next to be outside the click event. Otherwise it will always ZERO. on every click.

Comment: You've used `</select>` an extra time.

Comment: I think you mean: `<input type="checkbox">` instead of the `<select>`.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, are you sure about `var = orders = 0`?  Was it edited?  I see `var orders = 0` and it's outside the `addEventListener`.  * I think it should be indented and aligned, and that there should be a `;` at the end,

Comment: @poni, is there an HTML element with `id="orders"`?  I don't see it - can you show us?

Comment: @poni, I assume you close the `<form>` tag (I don't know if it's good practice, but - unless I send the data using HTML, I don't use forms, just the inputs, and - after collecting them, I send through javascript).

Comment: @poni, if you have `<button id="orders">Place Order</button>`, and changed  `<select id="bigger"></select>` to `<input type="checkbox" id="bigger">` - your code should work.

Comment: I dont care about my HTML because it works just fine, my problem right now is how to assign an order number to every order

Comment: @poni, your code will work if you have an HTML element with `id=orders`...

Comment: Please post all relevant parts of the HTML don't skip off the element with id="orders"

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="condiments" id="condiments">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
  <label for="bigger">Make theese bigger:</label>
  <select id="bigger"></select>
  <button id="orders">Place Order</button>
```

```js
  var order= 0;

  document.getElementById("orders").addEventListener("click", numOrder);

  function numOrder() {
    var setOrder = document.getElementById("orders");
    setOrder.value = order;
    order++;
  }
```

Note that `setOrder.value` is stored as a string.  Should you need to convert to number, use `parseInt(setOrder.value)`.

Comment: This does not work as expected. Please review your answer :) where is `orders` is defined.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, "expected" in this question has a (very) loose "definition"... :)  As I understood it - my answer works...  The `value` within the button increases because it is set to the global js var `order` that is increased through js code...

Comment: Agree - But I was taking about the click event - where do the OP will click so the `numOrder` function can be called ? I do not see any button or div with `id` `orders` to it.

Comment: Yes what i was highlighting - Thanks alot. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Note: order values here are zero-based = the first one will be zero.
You can change that = to start with one, by either setting order to 1, or by moving order++ to the first line of the function.
Anyways - if you like my answer, please select and up-vote it.  Thanks!